Multiplexer with transmission gates
I have a multiplexer with 2 selection bits (S0 and S1), 4 inputs (x0, x1, x2, x3) and 1 output (y).
The truth table for this circuit is the following:



S1
S0
y




0
0
x0


0
1
x1


1
0
x2


1
1
x3



I also have the following implementation using CMOS transmission gates

Is this implementation correct ? For x1 when S0 is 1 and S1 is 0 shouldn't the gates act as open circuits ?

The implementation is almost correct. On the schematic, you interchanged S0 and S1. Leave schematic unchanged, just swap the S1 designation with S0 - leave the inversions alone, they are OK.

For x1 when S0 is 1 and S1 is 0 shouldn't the gates act as open circuits ?

Correct. That’s because the left gate should be taking S1, and the right gate S0, with inversion bars as they currently are for each gate.
